# Ball point picking, I just need the radius

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, algorithms

I want to pick points uniformly in the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

First of all, I don't believe the formula $\frac{(X_1, \dots, X_n)}{\sqrt{Y+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}}$ given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallPointPicking.html). For $n=2$ my simulation puts too many points nearer to the boundary!

Then again, I only need the radius of the random point in the unit ball. Can you give me the formula of its pdf?

Is the following true:

For $n=1$ it's uniform

For $n=2$ it's $2x$

For $n=3$ it's $3x^2$

$\vdots$

For general $n$ it's $nx^{n-1}$?

I got this with $P(R<r) = \frac{V(B(0, r))}{V(B(0, 1))} = r^n$, (scaling in dimension $n$).

Comment: I agree! I think it is because a typo has crept into the formulae at some stage, which has then been copied across to secondary sources. From what I can tell, Y should be drawn from an exponential with parameter = 1/2 and not 1, as originally written.

Comment: my blog post at http://extremelearning.com.au/how-to-generate-uniformly-random-points-on-n-spheres-and-n-balls/  lists all of the most common methods to pick uniformly from an n-dimensional ball, including the two that you mention.

Comment: and finally, Dap's answer can be reconciled with this because an exp(1/2), and not an exp(1), variable Y has the same distribution as $Y_1^2+Y_2^2$ where $Y_1,Y_2$ are standard normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly derived the pdf, and your reasoning is correct: the cdf is $r^n,$ and the pdf is its derivative. You can sample this variable by taking $Z^{1/n}$ where $Z$ is uniform on $[0,1].$

If the mathworld ball picking formula is giving the wrong results, I am certain you have a mistake in your implementation. It has a nice geometrical explanation: the first $n$ co-ordinates of a random point in the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{n+2}$ are uniformly distributed in the $n$-dimensional ball in $\mathbb R^n.$ See for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33129/intuitive-proof-that-the-first-n-2-coordinates-on-a-sphere-are-uniform-in-a. To tie this to the formula note that an Exp(1) variable $Y$ has the same distribution as $Y_1^2+Y_2^2$ where $Y_1,Y_2$ are standard normal.